# It's possible to make that Javers run with database synonyms or avoid table creation?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, javers

I need that javers run in another database but in the same transaction. 
I have a microservice Jhipser App and I can't configure JTA for both datasources in MS-Sql, So I think that if I have a synonym otherwise table maybe I can do that javers works like I want.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried Javers with JTA but it should be possible. JaVers is not managing transactions, your applications does it. Moreover, JaVers is not managing sql connections, your applications provides a live sql connection to any database you need.
See https://javers.org/documentation/repository-configuration/#connection-provider